# CTI Call Centre: You can't add these users because they’re already assigned to another phone in Salesforce

Tags: cti, call-center

We are trying to add a `User` to the `Call Centre` in an `SDO`, but when we select the user and try and add them, we get this error message:

> You can't add these users because they’re already assigned to another phone in Salesforce

And when we try and change the `Call Centre` via the `User` profile, we get this error:

> Error: You can't add a call center because users can't be assigned to both Voice and Call Center (Open CTI).

We've deleted the previous two `Call Centres` from the org, yet we still get the error.

**Questions**

1. What other ways might the `User` be linked to a `CTI Phone` in Salesforce?
2. What do we need to unlink the `User` so we can add them to our new `Call Centre`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely to be because Lightning Voice and/or Dialer is configured.  Check for the permission sets against the user, remove them, then remove the 'permission set license assignments' (Dialer Inbound User, Dialer Outbound User & Dialer Minutes).  This will free up the user to be reassigned to a call centre.